# fragment inside fragment in MainActivity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, methods, fragment

I hav an activity and inside it I have a fragment (A) that holds fragment (B) and in fragment (B) I have a button that goes back to fragment (A).

The problem is that I want to go back to my MainActivity from fragment (A) that came from that button in fragment (B).

it takes 3 onbackpressed to go back to MainActivity
I just want to go back in 1 onbackpressed

Answer (score 0):

Open fragment with TAG, because you check fragment is currently open or not by using TAG

```
    IntroFragment introFragment = IntroFragment.newInstance(activity);
    FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.frame, introFragment, "INTRO");
    ft.commit();
```

in fragment to open fragment replace `getSupportFragmentManager()` with `getChildFragmentManager()`

Remove fragment using below code

```
Fragment oldFragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("INTRO");
if (oldFragment != null)
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(oldFragment).commit();
```

Place your own logic in your activity `onBackPressed();`

Comment: but where to do this code

Fragment oldFragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("INTRO");
if (oldFragment != null)
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(oldFragment).commit();

Comment: in your fragment and call fragment method in your main activity backpressed